# How can I resolve this libgomp1 dependency issue?

Tags: ubuntu, compiling, gcc

I'm trying to build and install ccminer on Ubuntu 16.04 and getting the following error:

```
scrypt.cpp:(.text+0xa55b): undefined reference to `GOMP_parallel'
scrypt.cpp:(.text+0xa6cd): undefined reference to `GOMP_parallel'
```

libgomp1 is installed :

```
Package: libgomp1
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: libs
Installed-Size: 156
Maintainer: Ubuntu Core developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Multi-Arch: same
Source: gcc-5
Version: 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5
Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5), libc6 (>= 2.17)
Breaks: gcc-4.3 (<< 4.3.6-1), gcc-4.4 (<< 4.4.6-4), gcc-4.5 (<< 4.5.3-2)
Description: GCC OpenMP (GOMP) support library
 GOMP is an implementation of OpenMP for the C, C++, and Fortran compilers
 in the GNU Compiler Collection.
Homepage: http://gcc.gnu.org/
Original-Maintainer: Debian GCC Maintainers <debian-gcc@lists.debian.org>
```

and the libraries are found here:

```
locate libgomp

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libgomp.a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libgomp.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libgomp.spec
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1.0.0
/usr/share/doc/libgomp1
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgomp1:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgomp1:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgomp1:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgomp1:amd64.symbols
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgomp1:amd64.triggers
```

Is it possible to specifiy the location of the libraries in a config / makefile somehow?

the makefile contains:

```
OPENMP_CFLAGS = -fopenmp
```

In case it is relevant, I have Anaconda installed as I have read that this can interfere with some build processes.

Link to VERBOSE output of build.sh

[output gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d0151ef2e99ee1b8dc17b42f37b7fc8a)

gcc and g++ versions:

```
g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) 5.4.0 20160609

gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) 5.4.0 20160609
```

Comment: First step is to see the actual `gcc` commandline and inspect the `-L` options etc. You may have to (temporarily) edit the makefile if it suppresses that line.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the specific version of `ccminer` you’re trying to build? It looks like the build is failing because `-fopenmp` is only provided to the compiler, and not to the linker.

Comment: ccminer version https://github.com/tpruvot/ccminer/wiki/Compatibility

Comment: +1 to @dirkt suggestion.  Modify `build.sh` so the make invocation looks like `make VERBOSE=1`.  Then find include your gcc/ld invocations in the question

Comment: also include your `./configure` invocation parameters

Comment: ./configure has no invocation parameters in build.sh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same problem and, as predicted by OP, my issue was related to an Anaconda install and it got fixed after removing it.
I noticed that running `locate libgomp` produced an output similar to OPs but with Anaconda related results at the top.

After uninstalling it, the output was the same and I became able to build ccminer with default configs.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40159908) details simply how to uninstall Anaconda

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using the distribution's default gcc version (probably 6 or 7).  Per the INSTALL document, gcc 5 is the only version supported.  You can check the version with `gcc --version`.  To change the version on Ubuntu run the following:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-5 g++-5
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-5 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-5 1
```

Comment: This was what I meant with my link.

Comment: thanks but I've already done this. gcc --version shows 5.4

Comment: and what does g++ show?

Comment: g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) 5.4.0 20160609

Comment: `g++ --version`.  You can have as many compilers installed as you want - I want to know which one you're using

Comment: my assumtion is that the default versions on my system are being used. I did not prepare the ```make``` or ```configure``` files but previous advice to run make with verbose output just shows calls to ```gcc``` and ```g++```.The gist linked in the question shows these calls.  I don't know anything about ```gcc``` or ```g++``` which is why I probably sound clueless.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much experience you have with compiling, but in general, having a library installed isn't necessarily enough. To compile against a library, you also need to have the development headers installed. The package for that is usually called [library-name]-dev, so check and make sure that is installed. For that one, it will probably be called 'libgomp1-dev' in the package installer, or something similar.

That error you posted looks like a compiler error. What did the configure script say about libgomp, when you ran it? It usually checks for the dependent libraries.

**Edit:**

The header files are usually stored in `/usr/include` or `/usr/local/include` by default. I just had a look in mine and I don't see any headers that look like they relate to libgomp. I also have the libgomp1 package installed, but not libgomp1-dev. In fact, there doesn't seem to be a libgomp1-dev package available in my distro's repository (Trisquel 7, based on Ubuntu). I recommend that you look into which header file it is supposed to be using and where you can get hold of that.

Comment: `libgomp` linking is managed by GCC, there is no corresponding `-dev` package (or rather, it’s part of `libgcc-?-dev` with the appropriate version instead of the question mark).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. That explains why I couldn't find the -dev package for libgomp then :-). So, it seems like codecowboy needs to check that he has the correct GCC dev package installed?

Comment: libgcc-5-dev is already the newest version (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5).

Comment: Did you find https://github.com/tpruvot/ccminer/blob/windows/INSTALL

Comment: headers aren't the issue - linker can't find the symbols.  Headers are used during the compilation phase

Comment: @Bahamut spot on man - gcc 5 dependency

Comment: I have already followed the linked document and installed both gcc and g++ version 5.